# "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list" how do I approach this

Tags: python, list, for-loop, pycharm

I am fairly new to python and I am trying to display the BMI, however i am getting an error stating

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list:
```

I am not sure how to display this list

```
def bmi(n):
    for x in range(0,n+1):
        if len(x)<18.5:
            return False
        if len(x)>=18.5 and len(x)<=24.9:
            return True
        if len(x)>=25.0 and len(x)<=29.9:
            return False
        if len(x)>=30.0:
            return False
massindex=[18.5, 24.9, 29.9, 40.0]
for mass in massindex:
    print('\nA BMI under', mass, 'is a healthy BMI?', bmi(massindex))
```

Comment: Please review the functions you are using and the logic. I think understanding loops, data type structures and the function len will help you solve the issue.

Comment: You probably meant to do `bmi(mass)` instead of `bmi(massindex)`. `massindex` is the _entire list_. When you pass this to `bmi` as `n`, `n + 1` is trying to add an integer to a list. `mass` is the element you're currently processing. Also your  `bmi` function won't work because `x` will be an integer and therefore `len(x)` is meaningless.  [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have decided to fix your function to account for the goal you are trying to achieve. The solution I propose is to iterate over the different values in the massindex list and perform the comparison in your function. Also, given the results, since `n>=25` and `n>=30` are both False, you can simplify it in n>= 25 False, no need for both criteria if the result is the same:

```
def bmi(n):
  if n<18.5:
    return False
  elif n>=18.5 and n<=24.9:
    return True
  else: #Any value that doesn't the previous criteria (n > 24.9)
    return False
massindex=[18.5, 24.9, 29.9, 40.0]
for mass in massindex:
    print('\nA BMI under', mass, 'is a healthy BMI?', bmi(mass))
```

The main problem with your solution, is the `for` loop inside your function, there's no need for it, because you are iterating over the list in the `for` loop outside the function (when you do `for mass in massindex:`). Therefore, your function should take each of the values in `massindex` list and perform the comparisons to check whether it should return True or False. Also, since you are comparing values, the `len()` function is unnecessary, as it returns the number of elements in a list, which does not serve any purpose for this particular case.

Comment: Will add a detailed explanation, the main issue is, you can choose 2 ways to fix the code, by removing the loop in the function and iterating through each value in a list and applying the function, or accepting a list in the function and iterating inside it in the function. OP mistake is a combination of both, unclear which one they prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! I was just wondering why the for loop wouldn't work with the n value? Is it because of different data types?

Comment: Yes, first of all, massindex is a list, and the function `range()` accepts integers, so range(0,massindex+1)` doesn't make sense because you can't sum 1 to a list, nor use it as a value for the `range()` function. I suggest you read about data types and functions: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datatypes.asp to get a better understanding.

Comment: oh okok sure thing! Thank You again!